# change code from template engine to next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pug

How do I convert my app that is made with .pug to next app ? I have an app using .pug engine and I want to convert it into next.
This is the `app.js` but as I know next is different how do I do it? Because here my files are in views, and in views the files are in pages etc how do I do it? Is there any way or I have to code it all again?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port =  process.env.PORT || 3000;
const middleware = require('./middleware')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const mongoose = require("./database");
const session = require("express-session");
const http = require('http');

const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server listening on port " + port));
const io = require("socket.io")(server, { pingTimeout: 60000 });

app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", "views");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use(session({
    secret: "#########",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))

// Routes
const loginRoute = require('./routes/loginRoutes');
const registerRoute = require('./routes/registerRoutes');
const logoutRoute = require('./routes/logout');
const postRoute = require('./routes/postRoutes');
const profileRoute = require('./routes/profileRoutes');
const uploadRoute = require('./routes/uploadRoutes');
const searchRoute = require('./routes/searchRoutes');
const messagesRoute = require('./routes/messagesRoutes');
const notificationsRoute = require('./routes/notificationRoutes');

// Api routes
const postsApiRoute = require('./routes/api/posts');
const usersApiRoute = require('./routes/api/users');
const chatsApiRoute = require('./routes/api/chats');
const messagesApiRoute = require('./routes/api/messages');
const notificationsApiRoute = require('./routes/api/notifications');

app.use("/login", loginRoute);
app.use("/register", registerRoute);
app.use("/logout", logoutRoute);
app.use("/posts", middleware.requireLogin, postRoute);
app.use("/profile", middleware.requireLogin, profileRoute);
app.use("/uploads", uploadRoute);
app.use("/search", middleware.requireLogin, searchRoute);
app.use("/messages", middleware.requireLogin, messagesRoute);
app.use("/notifications", middleware.requireLogin, notificationsRoute);

app.use("/api/posts", postsApiRoute);
app.use("/api/users", usersApiRoute);
app.use("/api/chats", chatsApiRoute);
app.use("/api/messages", messagesApiRoute);
app.use("/api/notifications", notificationsApiRoute);

app.get("/", middleware.requireLogin, (req, res, next) => {

    var payload = {
        pageTitle: "Home",
        userLoggedIn: req.session.user,
        userLoggedInJs: JSON.stringify(req.session.user),
    }

    res.status(200).render("home", payload);
})

io.on("connection", socket => {

    socket.on("setup", userData => {
        socket.join(userData._id);
        socket.emit("connected");
    })

    socket.on("join room", room => socket.join(room));
    socket.on("typing", room => socket.in(room).emit("typing"));
    socket.on("stop typing", room => socket.in(room).emit("stop typing"));
    socket.on("notification received", room => socket.in(room).emit("notification received"));

    socket.on("new message", newMessage => {
        var chat = newMessage.chat;

        if(!chat.users) return console.log("Chat.users not defined");

        chat.users.forEach(user => {
            
            if(user._id == newMessage.sender._id) return;
            socket.in(user._id).emit("message received", newMessage);
        })
    });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to refactor all your `pug` template engine pages to next.js pages, then you can make the `pug` pages coexist with the next.js. You can make the next.js the default route, and place next.js code after all `pug` page routes. And you also need to refactor `app.get("/", middleware.requireLogin, (req, res, next) => {...}` to make sure next.js is the default route.
To apply this rule, you need a [custom next.js server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server).

#### sample code

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const port = 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'; // use default NodeJS environment variable to figure out dev mode
const app = next({dev, conf});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const server = express();


// all your pug page routes should be declared before `server.get('*'`.

server.get('*', authMiddleware(false), (req, res) => {
    // pass through everything to NextJS
    return handle(req, res);
});

app.prepare().then(() => {
    server.listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('NextJS is ready on http://localhost:' + port);
    });

}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e.stack);
    process.exit(1);

});
```

Comment: Oh, so when i do that it would be an Next app and i would be able to use it as a PWA just like we use next app as pwa without engines right bro ?

Comment: How do i add next js into this ? like create-next-app will create another app so how do i add it add next into this existing app bro

Comment: Last thing where i have to place the pages folder and what files should be in that folder ? my views folder inside the pages folder am i right

Comment: I don't know PWA though. There are many tutorials and demos in the official site of next.js.You can try to run a simple next.js app firstly, and later you add `express` to it and make it a custom server. You pug files can stay at their original place. Next.js requires the `pages` directory in the root or in the src/ of root.

Comment: what i did is used ( npm install next react react-dom
 ) and added the Pages folder and i moved the views folder into the Pages folder ....... Should i keep it outside or what or can you help me with this in messages bro it would mean alot to me

Comment: I suggest you put next.js `pages` in src foler, and put pug file somewhere else, just not in `pages`. It's ok to do not move those `pug` files if it requires too much refactoring work.

Comment: okay thank you so much, by the way can you come on chat and help me with this process, its not that big i just want to convert, it is the first time i am doing something like this bro, would mean alot if you can

Comment: i dont know any way we can chat ? slack ? anything you can use to collaborate